# Command-line .fla to .swf file compilation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, automation

I have to create about 30 different .swf from a single .fla, where the only difference between them are a couple actionscript 3 strings, used to set some text on the final .swf.

My current approach is to do it manually, change the strings on each .fla and compile to .swf. Naturally, this takes a lot of time and it's a task that can be done more efficiently.

The new approach I would like to take is to edit the strings in the .fla files (in its XLF form) using some other programming language, and then use a command-line tool to compile to .swf. If such command-line tools exists (and for linux), then I can create an interface on a web app that automatically generates these files on request.

So far, I haven't been able to find any command-line tool that suits my purpose. And although there are similar stackoverflow questions on this matter, these are very old and maybe a tool like this exists now. If this is not the case, what other approach would you recommend in order to automate this tedious task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't command line `fla->swf` tools, but you can consider two options:

1. you can do all the work that you done manually but with the `JSFL` script. You can also write `*.bat` script (or `bash` for Linux) for launching this jsfl. In this case you still need `Flash Pro` for building.
2. consider to modify your `fla` in a such a way, when you can use it as an asset for the `mxmlc` project, so you can embed this swf, create asset in runtime, apply your changes using [mxmlc conditional compiling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html) and add child to the stage. In this case you need `Flash Pro` only for building your asset.